Playwright component testning: my local function always returns undefined
@playwright/experimental-ct-react: 1.49.0
@playwright/test: 1.49.0

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour when using Playwright component testning with React.
I pass a callback function down to the component being tested and even though the implentation always returns a string, when it is called during the testrun it appears to return undefined.
I think this is related to this line of code in playwright.
export async function unwrapObject(value: any): Promise<any> {
  return transformObjectAsync(value, async (v: any) => {
    if (isFunctionRef(v)) {
      const result = (...args: any[]) => {
        window.__ctDispatchFunction(v.ordinal, args); // <-- this line doesn't return a value
      };
      return { result };
    }
    if (isImportRef(v))
      return { result: await window.__pwRegistry.resolveImportRef(v) };
  });
}

Because when I log the name of the function to be called I get this output:
(...args) => {
  window.__ctDispatchFunction(v.ordinal, args);
} 

It looks like my function is wrapped in something and that this something calls the function, but doesn't return its return value.
See this repo which demonstrates the problem

Did you try the return keyword? This code is rather unusual--what are you trying to do exactly?

All the code shown is from the playwright repo :-) and I suspect it is missing the return keyword, because I can see my function is being called and it returns a value, but somehow this value is not "passed down" to my other code. I suspect playwright is wrapping the function and using the unwrapObject function shown above.

Got it, I misunderstood, but then where's your component testing code that somehow invokes this internal function, and what are you trying to achieve in your test at a high level?

It's at bit complicated and hard to share. I was hoping someone with knowledge of the playwright code might see the line and conclude that it should return the value of the function call. When invoking the result variable, the outcome will always be undefined which I don't think was intended.

Better to simplify your code and show how you're calling it. I doubt anyone will know this offhand except for maybe one or two maintainers that aren't active here, and even that's a stretch. If there's a bug with Playwright, a [mcve] would be necessary to report it on GitHub anyway.

I have now created a repo on GitHub that demonstrates the error.

Thanks for taking the time to make it. The code should be in the question itself, per the guidelines posted above. External links can disappear over time. That said, I didn't run it, but it looks like a reasonable repo, so I'd probably just post this on PW issues if it's a legitimate bug.

It is by design not possible to do this. See this comment on GitHub.
